# Property 'initializeOnMount' required in type 'MoralisProviderInitializedProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, moralis

I was getting an **error** due to the following code snippet:

> Type '{ children: Element; appId: string | undefined; serverUrl: string | undefined; }'
> is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MoralisProviderProps'.
> Property 'initializeOnMount' is missing in type '{ children: Element; appId: string |
> undefined; serverUrl: string | undefined; }' but required in type
> 'MoralisProviderInitializedProps'.ts(2322)
> MoralisProvider.d.ts(19, 5): 'initializeOnMount' is declared here.

**Here's my _app.jsx**

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { MoralisProvider } from "react-moralis";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }:any) {

return (

 < MoralisProvider
   appId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID}
   serverUrl={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL} >

 <Component {...pageProps} />

 </MoralisProvider>

        );
 }

 export default MyApp;
```

Even deploying on **vercel** gave this same error:
[image]

[image]

Comment: The error tells you exactly the prop that is missing from the component: you need to pass in `initializeOnMount`

Comment: Yes, it worked. Their doc says to pass it as false. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

Just to further elaborate on my comment: the error you're getting informs you that the prop `initializeOnMount` is missing from your `<MoralisProvider>` component, as the typing indicates as such. It does appear to be an inconsistency with their documentation, as [their example clearly leaves out the prop](https://github.com/MoralisWeb3/react-moralis#initialize).

However, it seems like this can be fixed by simply setting `initializeOnMount={false}` on the component itself:

```
<MoralisProvider
  appId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID}
  serverUrl={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}
  initializeOnMount={false}>
  <Component {...pageProps} />
</MoralisProvider>
```

Comment: Hey I actually was able to start ```npm run dev``` without error but on loading local host 3000, I am getting another kind of error.
"Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Moralis.Web3.onAccountsChanged is not a function"